# Jquery UI Slider Pips throws "No such method 'pips' for slider widget instance" in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, woocommerce, jquery-ui-slider-pips

I am working on a review option for a webshop in WooCommerce for one of my clients.
Now I want to use the jQuery UI Slider Pips extension.

All works fine on a [testpage on my own server](http://dev.sames-media.nl/test/).
And all works fine in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SAMES/r2au1v6g/) as well.

But I got an "Uncaught Error: no such method 'pips' for slider widget instance"-error in my WP installation.

I have tried to overrule the default WP jQuery version with the one from the fiddle, but nothing seems to work.

[Here](http://winkel.vormgegeven.nl/product/360-stoel/#review_form) the page that I am testing on.

Can you help me please !

My (Rendered) HTML

```
<select name="rating" id="rating">
    <option value="">Geen Mening</option>
    <option value="1">Zeer slecht</option>
    <option value="2">Niet slecht</option>
    <option value="3">Gemiddeld</option>
    <option value="4">Goed</option>
    <option value="5">Perfect</option>
</select>
```

My JS

```
var optionsdropdown = $( "#rating" );
var doubleLabels = new Array();

optionsdropdown.find('option').each(function() {
    //alert($j(this).val()+' :: '+$j(this).text());
    doubleLabels.push( '<i>' + $(this).val() + '</i><span>' + $(this).text() + '</span>' );
});

var slider = $( "<div id='double-label-slider'></div>" ).insertAfter( optionsdropdown );    
$("#double-label-slider")
.slider({
    min: 0,
    max: $('#rating > option').length - 1,
    animate: 400,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        optionsdropdown[ 0 ].selectedIndex = ui.value;
    }
})
.slider('pips', { 
    rest: 'label', 
    labels: doubleLabels
});
```

Comment: Please see my answer. I met the same problem and solve in 5 hours of brainstorming.

Comment: You need to check this answer to help others with same problem.
Nowadays people believe answer with questioner's tick.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for Rails. But I hope this helps you.

You have to insert following line to `application.js`

`//=jquery-ui-slider-pips.min`

I've found this answer after 5 hours of brainstorming.