# Rails: jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips: Error: no such method 'pips' for slider widget instance

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rangeslider, jquery-ui-slider-pips

Using the plugin from -> http://simeydotme.github.io/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips/#getting-started
Even though the slider loads, no Pips get loaded.

Rails 5 with JQuery

```
1: Downloaded  jquery-ui-slider-pips.css under myApp/app/assets/stylesheets

2: Downloaded jquery-ui-slider-pips.js under myApp/app/assets/javascripts

3: application.js 

//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery-ui-slider-pips

4: application.css

 *= require jquery-ui-slider-pips

5: In the View
    <!-- include the jQuery and jQuery UI scripts -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <!-- plus a jQuery UI theme, here I use "flick" -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="slider"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {

    $(".slider")
        .slider({
            max: 12
        })
        .slider("pips", {
            rest: "label"
        });
 });
</script>
```

The slider loads with no pips and Error: no such method 'pips' for slider widget instance in browser console. 
Can anyone please help?

Comment: This post might be helpful  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37319159/jquery-ui-slider-pips-throws-no-such-method-pips-for-slider-widget-instance

Comment: I have already added //= require jquery-ui-slider-pips

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to add;

```html
<script src="/path/to/jquery-ui-slider-pips.js"></script>
```

to your "view" ... I don't know rails at all, so I'm taking a leap here.

Alternatively you can use the official source:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips/1.11.4/jquery-ui-slider-pips.js"></script>
```

---

But I do recognise that I've missed a crucial step in the docs which has the effect of making it seem unnecessary! I'll update as soon as I can